# jQuery Multiple getJSON requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My script needs to fetch several json files on https://graph.facebook.com/xxxx, and retrieve a certain field from each json, then calculate summation.

My problem is how to print out the result after all getJSON done? With below code it will prints 0. Feel free to suggest any better approaches.

```
var result = 0;
$.each(urls, function (i, url) {
    $.getJSON(url, function (json) {
        result += json.field1;
    })
});
alert(result);
```

Comment: Would you mind to post an example json object? Even though Facebook is the biggest social network side, not all users -like me- are registered at facebook. Thx

Comment: example object is irrelevant :) see answer below

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using jQuery 1.5 deferred objects:

Accumulate an array of the JQXHR objects returned by `$.getJSON()`

```
var jxhr = urls.map(function(url) {
    return $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
        result += json.field1;
    })
});
```

and only `$.when` they're all `.done()`:

```
$.when.apply($, jxhr).done(function() {
    alert(result);
});
```

NB: this will accumulate `result` in the order that the AJAX calls complete, not in the order they're made.

Comment: @Alnitak how can i handle, if the getJson failed, because the url dont exist?

Answer (score 3):

It's not working as you are printing the result straight away, remember that the code where you concatenate the result is a callback so will fire after your alert.

On each callback you'll have to check if all have finished. replace the alert() call with your processing. :)

```
    var result = 0;
    var doneCount = 0;

    $.each(urls, function (i, url) {
        $.getJSON(url, function (json) {
            doneCount++;
            result += json.field1;
            if (doneCount == urls.length) {
                alert(result);
            }
        })
    });
```