# How do I know when the last async is done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have something like this:

```
for (var i=0;i<result.qry.ROWCOUNT;i++) {
  myAsync(i);
}
```

How do I know when all my Async functions have finished executing?

At the risk of someone replying with "Needs more jQuery!", can I use the jQuery promise object?  Or deferred or something like that?

Comment: With jQuery you can use `.done()` or `.then()` combined with `$.when()`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5817886/1095206

Comment: Thank you very much.  That is something I was looking for!

Answer (score 9):

Keep track of how many asynchronous calls are outstanding. When each finishes, decrement your counter. When you get to 0, you are in the last callback.

```
var asyncsLeft = 0;
for (var i=0;i<10;++i){
   asyncsLeft++;
   doSomethingAsyncWithCallback(function(){
     // This should be called when each asynchronous item is complete
     if (--asyncsLeft==0){
       // This is the last one!
     }
   });
}
```

*Due to the single-threaded nature of JavaScript there is no potential race condition where you might get your callback invoked before all of the asynchronous calls have been queued up. It is safe to put the `asyncsLeft++` call after the `doSomethingAsynchronous`, if you like.*

Comment: I'd suggest something similar: use two variables, one that tracts the total number of resources, and one that tracks how many have loaded/failed (possibly in two other variables). With one variable, you risk the slight chance that a request will finish before the code makes a new one, which will prematurely assume everything's loaded (yes, this has actually happened to me). In addition, using two variables can show the progress of loaded resources.

Comment: @JeffreySweeney If you kick them all off in a single loop, then no, you do not run that risk. That's what my italicized text is about. No callbacks will start being invoked until after your `for` loop is finished.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

```
//Do stuff up here to get records
var rowCount = result.qry.ROWCOUNT, //Save the row count
    asyncCount = 0, //The count of complete async calls
    asyncCallback = function() {
        //To be called whenever an async operation finishes
        asyncCount++; //Increment the row counter
        if (asyncCount >= rowCount) {
            //Do stuff when they're all finished
        }
    };

for (var i=0;i<rowCount;i++) {
  myAsync(i, asyncCallback);
}

function myAsync(index, completeCallback) {
    //Do async stuff with index
    //Call completeCallback when async stuff has finished or pass it
    // into the async function to be called
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, there is the `$.ajaxStop` function that runs after the last Ajax has ran.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, you can also use the `ajaxSend` and `ajaxComplete` methods to keep your counter code separate from your dispatch code.

```
var ajaxPending = 0;

function ajax_changed(indicator, pending) {
    if (pending)
        $(indicator).show();
    else
        $(indicator).hide();
}

$('#loading-indicator').ajaxSend(function() {
    ajax_changed(this, ++ajaxPending);
});

$('#loading-indicator').ajaxComplete(function() {
    ajax_changed(this, --ajaxPending);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a callback function:

```
for (var i=0;i<result.qry.ROWCOUNT;i++) {
  myAsync(i, myCallback);
}

function myCallback(i){
  //set result.qry.ROWCOUNT to a var somewhere above if it's not available in this scope
  if(i == (result.qry.ROWCOUNT - 1)){
     //now you know you're actually done with all requests
  }
}
function myAsync(i,callback){
  ///do work
  callback(i);
}
```

Comment: This only works if the async tasks finish in the order they are started.

Comment: In this case, `myAsync` is synchronous, you'd have to pass the callback to whatever asynchronous methods/library you're using.