# How do I know when the last async task is done?

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I have some varied run time length SQL queries in separate SQL files that generate independent reports (I don't need to use results of any of them to feed to any other).

I'm running them from sync forEach with async con.query() and they do what I want.

**My question: How do I know when the last query is done ?**
Or, to be exact: when is the callback of the last query finished ?

Constrains:

- amount of queries can change
- time it takes to run them can change

Code:

```js
const sql_files = fs.readdirSync(sql_dir)

sql_files.forEach((sql_file) => {
    sql = fs.readFileSync('sql/'+sql_file).toString()
    con.query(sql, ( err, rows ) => {
        if (err) throw err
        __do_something_with_SQL()
    })
})
```

I'm fairly new to Node, and so far, the only way I've found would be to return a promise for each one and keep them in an array iirc (that would be a lot of additional boilerplate code to add, but couldn't find any simpler way).

I also found [How do I know when the last async is done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993047/how-do-i-know-when-the-last-async-is-done) - and I can do it with a counter, but I have a feeling there is some better way, maybe some built in global array/object ?

Comment: Maybe I'm old school, but IMO there's nothing wrong with a counter, it's simple, easy to understand code and it works well..

Comment: just use await on `await con.query`, the rest is sync, so right at the bottom after the forEach its complete, else the only way is keep decrementing a counter from original sql_files.length

Comment: if you want to have some fun with it, watch the counter and when it = sql_files.length fire of a function https://playcode.io/666635/ ;p