# Why don't multiple $.getJSON calls work properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, getjson

Please take a look at this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var urls = ['http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=File:Einstein2.jpg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&iiurlwidth=144&format=json&callback=?', 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=File:Da_Vinci_Vitruve_Luc_Viatour.jpg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&iiurlwidth=144&format=json&callback=?', 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=File:2003-32-GravitationalLens.jpg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&iiurlwidth=144&format=json&callback=?'];
        var x = 0;
        var f = function() {
            x++;
            console.log(x);
        };
        $.getJSON(urls[0], function(json) { f(); } );
        $.getJSON(urls[1], function(json) { f(); } );
        $.getJSON(urls[2], function(json) { f(); } );
    });
```

The result of this code is "1", while I was expecting "1 2 3".

I've seen solutions to this (for example, in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817811/jquery-multiple-getjson-requests)). But I still can't understand why the given solution should work and the code above shouldn't.

**ADDED:**
When I put some code between $.getJSON calls or change console.log() to alert(), output is really "1 2 3". When this methods are called exactly aften one another, in Chrome output becomes "1".

**ADDED:**
Strange thing. Without changing the code at all I got 3 different outputs "1", "1 2", "1 2 3" just by reloading the page...

Comment: What result do you expect? What result do you get? Define "work properly"

Comment: The result of running that code *is* 1 2 3 — http://jsfiddle.net/njxR7/ . You appear to have produced a reduced test case that has reduced away the problem to nothing.

Comment: Quentin is right ... the result is 123 ... but the 1 doesn't necessarily come from the first $.getJSON. See modified example http://jsfiddle.net/GG8Uf/

Comment: @Quentin, when I put some code between $.getJSON calls or change console.log() to alert(), output is really "1 2 3". When this methods are called exactly aften one another, in Chrome output becomes "1".

Comment: Strange thing. Without changing the code at all I got 3 different outputs "1", "1 2", "1 2 3" just by reloading the page...

Comment: I'm getting 1 2 3 every single time in Chrome, using a copy/paste of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/Encosia/McYjd/. It shouldn't make a difference, but what browser are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to nest the queries like this

```
 $.getJSON(urls[0], function(json) { 

    f();

     $.getJSON(urls[1], function(json) { f();

      $.getJSON(urls[2], function(json) { f(); 
      } );

     } );

   } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example actually is functioning the way you intend it.  In both Firefox and Chrome I see in my console output:

```
1
2
3
```